# How can I insert a multidimensional array in another array(int not char)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, int

I want an example showing how I can insert an 2D int array in another 1D int array? I am in a dead end here.

Comment: I thin you really want to specify what you mean. There are many way to put the elements of a 2D array into a 1D array. If you clarify you might actually get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// 2D int array
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > twoDarray;

// 1D array **of 2D arrays, not ints **
std::vector<twoDarray> oneDarray;

// Instance of 2D array
oneDarray myOneDArray;

// Instance of 2D array
twoDarray myTwoDArray;

// Add this in.
myOneDArray.push_back(myTwoDArray);
```

Comment: These are not arrays. These are vectors. Take a look at `std::array`.

Comment: @Tomalak, The OP did not specify c++0x.

Comment: @Nim: Then `boost::array`, or `tr1::array`, or native arrays. Regardless of what flavour of C++ you use, what you demonstrated are not arrays.

Comment: @Tomalak, and what's wrong with `vector` as a recommendation?

Comment: @Nim: Nothing, but you wrote "array" as a comment every place you used a vector.

Comment: @Tomalak, C++0x _is_ C++. Just like how "common" C++ is C++98

Comment: @Tomalak, `<sigh/>` there was me thinking that that subtle highlight would emphasise a point...

Comment: @freedompeace: No it's not. When the FDIS is actually approved, there may be a case for that, but C++0x is so different that there's a good reason to make a distinction. Also, Nim's the one who brought it up.. not me.

Comment: @Nim: I don't understand what highlighting has to do with it. Perhaps I'm not being clear, or I'm misunderstanding you? Your answer appears to claim that `std::vector`s are arrays, when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

When you say insert, I'm assuming you mean "represent".  You can represent a 2D array in a 1D array in many ways, so long as you somehow make a 1-to-1 mapping between the 2D indexes and the 1D indexes.  For example:

```
storage[row*column_count + column]
```

Would be a typical, easy way to store the data at `row, column` within a 1D array (or `vector`).